# Getting Use to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, root

I am just getting familiar with MongoDB and its my first time to use it. I am using Ubuntu enviornment for the development. I installed the MongoDB as per the instructions mentioned in the tutorial available on the MongoDb website. They said that the data will be stored in the /data/db, now i have two question about this

1) Where do i need to make this folder? means which directory?
2) I made one directory in the root directory `/` and then i ran the `mongo` server. I made one database with the name of `movies` with `use movies` command and then put some collection in it like `action and comedy` and then each collection i saved some documents with `db.action.insert` and `db.comedy.insert` command and when i tried to find it in /data/db folder i found three files and one folder but there is no file with the name of movies so my question is with what name my database is saved.

Please guide me in this aspect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Mongo stores all of its DB files in the root of the configured `dbdir` directory.  Look into the `directoryperdb` configuration option if you want Mongo to create a separate directory for each database and place the database files within it.

The default data directory `/data/db` needs to be created by you if it hasn't been already.
You can do this in Ubuntu via the shell:

`CTL+ALT+T` to bring up a Terminal window:

```
cd /
sudo mkdir /data
cd data
sudo mkdir db
```

Note: you may also need to change ownership of the new directory to be owned by you:

```
sudo chown your_user_name /data
```

Note: my Mongo installation defaulted to a dbdir of `/var/lib/mongodb`

You can also choose a different data directory when you start Mongo:

```
mongod --dbdir some/dir
```

If Mongo is installed as a service, you should be checking the dbdir configuration option in your mongodb.conf file (again, when I installed Mongo, which I believe I did via the Software Center, it placed mongodb.conf at `/etc/mongodb.conf`)

Hope this helps

Comment: Dear Sir, i checked the `data/db` directory and it exists there but inside it there is no database with the name of `movies`...which i created.

Comment: My guess is that your configuration (mongodb.config) is pointing to a different location for --dbdir and therefore your databases are stored in that different location. You may check if /var/lib/mongodb directory exists - your databases may be there

Comment: rmirabelle...thanks for the detail reply..i got the respective directory...one more little question..do you have any idea about GridFS using C/C++ drivers?

Comment: sorry for the WAY late reply - no, I know nothing of those - I'm an amateur ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What are the 3 files you see? test*?

Here are the 2 more likely cases

- a) your DB files are into another location
- b) your data is in the test database

Go back to your shell and run:

```
use local
db.startup_log.find({},{startTimeLocal:1,cmdLine:1}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).pretty()

{
    "_id" : "mycomputer",
    "startTimeLocal" : "Mon Oct  7 09:44:25.353",
    "cmdLine" : {
        "config" : "mongodb.conf",
        "dbpath" : "./db",
        "fork" : "1",
        "journal" : "1",
        "logpath" : "./logs/mongo.log",
        "port" : 27017,
        "rest" : "1"
    }
}
```

=> dbpath tells you the location that was provided on the command line or config file

Again in the shell, run the following:

```
use test
show collections
use movies
show collections
```

If you see your collection names under test, you may not have used 'use movies' before creating the data.